# Помогите пожалуйста определить типы придаточных

Tags: синтаксис

*Она злилась на то, **(1)** что ее супруг пожертвовал собою для других, **(2)** меж тем как единственным справедливым самопожертвованием было бы жить и дальше для нее.*

(1) - придаточное изъяснительное?

(2) - до сегодня незнакомый мне союз *меж тем как*... имеет сходство с *в то время как*? может какое-то сопоставительное?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вы правы: это придаточное изъяснительное и придаточное сопоставительное. Союз  *меж те́м = между тем.*

Answer (score 2):

Она злилась на то, (1) что ее супруг пожертвовал собою для других, (2) меж тем как единственным справедливым самопожертвованием было бы жить и дальше для нее.

Предложение 2 - **придаточное сопоставительное со значением несоответствия** (союзы в то время как, между тем как, тогда как) + дополнительное противительное значение, так как первая часть противоречит второй. Дополнительных уступительных отношений здесь нет.

**Грамматическая справка**

Эти союзы (в то время как, между тем как, тогда как) сформировались на базе временной семантики, но сейчас эту семантику утратили и выступают только как сопоставительные союзы. В таких предложениях в зависимости от ЛЕКСИЧЕСКОГО НАПОЛНЕНИЯ могут выражаться противительные и  уступительные оттенки значения.

**Материал взят из книги Г. Кустова "Синтаксис современного русского языка" (2013 г).**

Таким образом, мы можем просто сопоставлять и обозначать простое несоответствие (вариант 1), а можем находить в ситуациях противоречие (вариант 2, доп. противительные отношения) или высказывать оценочные суждение (вариант 3, уступительные или возместительные отношения).

Answer (score 1):

> (1) - придаточное изъяснительное?

Да.

> (2) - до сегодня незнакомый мне союз меж тем как... имеет сходство с в
>   то время как?

Да, в этом предложении союз ***меж тем как*** синонимичен союзу ***в то время как***.

И, **по-моему**, союзу ***хотя***:

*Её супруг пожертвовал собою для других, **хотя** должен был жертвовать собою для неё.*

> может какое-то сопоставительное?

Я бы назвал это придаточное *уступительно-противительным*.

==================================================

> ...союзы в то время как, между тем как, тогда как... сформировались на
>   базе временной семантики, но сейчас эту семантику утратили и **выступают**
>   **только как сопоставительные союзы**.

Вот какие значения союза ***В ТО ВРЕМЯ <,> КАК*** отмечают  **Морковкин и др. в "Объяснительном словаре русского языка" (М., 2003)**:

1.0 **врем.** *…В то время как я познакомился с ним, он работал учителем.*

2.0 **сопоставит.** *…Я люблю балет, в то время как Аня предпочитает оперу.*

2.1 **сопоставит.-врем.** *…Мать готовила обед, в то время как дети делали уроки.*

3.0 **уступит.-противит.** …Син. ***тогда как*** употр. реже, ***между тем как*** употр. реже, ***хотя*** употр. чаще, ***хоть*** употр. чаще.

*Он принимал гостей, всё время улыбался, в то время как больше всего на свете ему хотелось побыть одному.*

3.1 **уступит.-противит.** …Син. ***тогда как*** употр. реже, ***между тем как*** употр. реже, ***хотя*** употр. чаще, ***хоть*** употр. чаще, ***но, однако, а, же, а между тем.***

*Твой приятель воображает себя героем, в то время как он просто выскочка и посредственность.*

========================================================

Впрочем, не все лингвисты квалифицируют предложения, подобные разбираемому нами, как сложноподчинённые.

**Кустова ("Синтаксис современного русского языка", М., 2013)**  отмечает, "что в АГ-80 предложения с союзами ***если … то, в то время как, тогда как, между тем как*** рассматриваются в составе сложносочинённых".

**В книге Формановской ("Сложное предложение в современном русском языке", М., 1989)** такие предложения безоговорочно включены в разряд "Сложносочинённые сопоставительные предложения".

**Скобликова ("Синтаксис сложного предложения", М., 2006)** о подобных предложениях пишет так:

> Однако есть и известная часть сложных предложений, которые трудно с
>   уверенностью отнести к одному или другому из двух основных традиционно
>   выделяемых разрядов. Это, например, предложения, выражающие
>   сопоставительно-противительные отношения с союзами ***тогда как, в то
>   время как, между тем как,   если... то***, типа:
>
> *"…всё кругом будто бы свидетельствовало о запустении, **между тем как** театр жил полнокровной творческой жизнью".*
>
> Предложения эти характеризуются смысловым равноправием частей, и
>   формально в них невозможно выделить главную и зависимую части; все они
>   синонимичны сложносочинённым предложениям с союзом ***"а"***.
>
> …В то же время характер употребляемых в них союзов не допускает
>   расчленения этих предложений на два отдельных простых предложения.
>   Поэтому, тяготея с сложносочинённым конструкциям, они являются не
>   вполне типичными и для этого разряда предложений.

**Бабайцева в монографии "Синтаксис русского языка" (М., 2015)** пишет:

> При делении сложных союзных предложений на сложносочинённые и
>   сложноподчинённые по характеру союзов и значению остаётся какая-то
>   часть сложных конструкций,  не обладающая полным набором… свойств ни
>   тех, ни других, а скорее совмещающая их. **Такие предложения или
>   вообще не учитываются при классификации, или получают разноречивые
>   оценки (одни учёные относят их к сложносочинённым, другие -- к
>   сложноподчинённым), или выделяются в особую группу сложных предложений
>   как "переходные между сочинением и подчинением".** Выделим некоторые
>   группы таких предложений...

В одну из этих групп Бабайцева включает и такие предложения:

> Предложения, части которых соединены союзами  **тогда как,  между тем
>   как, в то время как, если… то** и др.:
>
> *Отцы друг к другу не ездили, она Алексея ещё не видела, **между тем как** все молодые соседки только о нём и говорили…*

Comment: Слава, скажите, пожалуйста,а где здесь выражается противоречие с уступкой?